oaxaca-blinder export regressions results
I'm using the oaxaca command to do some analyze with a survey. While I get the decomposition results, I'd also like to export the full regressions outputs for each group. I mean the "Model for group 1" and the "Model for group 2". I tried using outreg2, but it only captures the decomposition.
Is there a way to export the complete regression details for each group?
Here is the code for reproduction
clear
set seed 1234
set obs 1000

* Variáveis independentes
gen educ = rnormal(12, 3)
gen experience = rnormal(5, 2)
gen tenure = rnormal(8, 2)
gen age = rnormal(35, 5)

* Variável dependente (por exemplo, salário)
gen salary = 1000 + 200*educ + 50*experience + 80*tenure + 30*age + rnormal(0, 1000)

* Variável dummy para sexo (0 para masculino, 1 para feminino)
gen female = runiform() < 0.5

* Adicionar pesos amostrais
gen weight = runiform()

* Sumarizar pesos amostrais
sum weight

* Definir dados como dados de pesquisa
svyset [pweight = weight]

* Estimar o modelo Oaxaca-Blinder
oaxaca salary educ experience tenure age, by(female) svy weight(1) swap noisily

I have tried something like this, but I coukdn't get the results of the two first regressions (Model for group 1" and the "Model for group 2")
estimates store model_group1

estimates store model_group2

outreg2 model_group1 model_group2 using resultados_modelos.xls

Someting similiar have been asked here (but not for survey): https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1421888-export-groups-model-using-oaxaca
Thanks in advance!
yes, I researched and tried this:
estimates store model_group1

estimates store model_group2

outreg2 model_group1 model_group2 using resultados_modelos.xls

